# mypy: type[list[Any]]" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pydantic

I have the following code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Worker(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    status: bool = True


class WorkerList(BaseModel):
    workers = list[Worker]

    def deactivate_worker(self, worker: Worker) -> None:
        for w in self.workers:
            if w.id == worker.id:
                w.status = False
                break
        raise ValueError(
            f"Cannot deactivate worker {worker.id}: Value doesn't exist"
        )
```

My code is really simple: I just want to have a function that changes the status of a Bool element (Worker) to False.

mypy is highlighting `self.workers` and giving me: `mypy: type[list[Any]]" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)`

What is the right way to deal with this?

Comment: You've written `workers = list[Worker]` as an assignment, not an annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77845246/mypy-typelistany-has-no-attribute-iter-not-iterable#:%7E:text=%E2%80%93-,user2357112,-5%20mins%20ago) already noted, you've used the annotation falsely as an assignment.

```
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Worker(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    status: bool = True


class WorkerList(BaseModel):
    workers: List[Worker] = []

    def deactivate_worker(self, worker: Worker) -> None:
        for w in self.workers:
            if w.id == worker.id:
                w.status = False
                break
        raise ValueError(f"Cannot deactivate worker {worker.id}: Value doesn't exist")
```